# Extracting observations that have a value in common from panel data

Tags: r, extract, panel-data

Let me explain my problem : I have a dataframe composed of household observations from 2011 and 2012. Each household has a specific ID number (character type) that allows to follow the household throughout the years. The thing is, I need to get only the households that appear both in 2011 and 2012 in order to see what evolve in the characteristics. Therefore I would like to extract from my dataset only the lines for which the household ID appears twice, but I really don't know how to do it.
If someone has an idea about that, I'd be really glad to it ! Thanks, cheers!

Comment: Can you add please how does data look like? Then, we can provide you the correct code to answer your question :-)

Comment: It's a set of 10000 observations (the rows) with 55 variables (columns). One column is the household ID and I have 265 duplicated households ID, meaning that 530 households ansewered the survey in the two years. Is that good enough for you to visualize it ? :)

Comment: I referred to print a `head(data)` to see the names in the explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There you go!

```
df <- data.frame(householdid = c(sample(1:10,5),sample(1:10,5)), year=c(rep(2011,5),rep(2012,5)))
#    householdid year
# 1            4 2011
# 2            7 2011
# 3            2 2011
# 4            3 2011
# 5            1 2011
# 6            5 2012
# 7            7 2012
# 8            4 2012
# 9            3 2012
# 10          10 2012
counts <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(df$householdid)),c("householdid","n"))
#   householdid n
# 1           1 1
# 2           2 1
# 3           3 2
# 4           4 2
# 5           5 1
# 6           7 2
# 7          10 1
hh_2y <- subset(counts,n==2)
#   householdid n
# 3           3 2
# 4           4 2
# 6           7 2
df_2y <- merge(df,hh_2y)
# householdid year n
# 1           3 2011 2
# 2           3 2012 2
# 3           4 2012 2
# 4           4 2011 2
# 5           7 2012 2
# 6           7 2011 2
```

Comment: Alright, I think I see the logic there :)
Thank you so much guys !